# routing in codeigniter - using company name on the end of the url instead of using the id

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have the following url:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/display/23 
// 23 is the companyid, and i want there to be company name
```

I would like to display it like

```
http://www.mydomain.com/display/company-name-here
```

Is it possible to fetch the company name from my controller somehow? Is this possible in the Codeigniter? How can i get the company name from my controller in the routes.php file? I check the CI documentation but I found...nothing.

Regards, John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `application/config/route.php` and add following route path

```
$route['display/company-name-here'] = 'display/index/23';
```

Hope `display` is controller name and you will have to use there `index` function.

Or another possible way

```
$route['display/(:any)'] = 'display/index/$1';
```

Note your link should be `http://www.mydomain.com/display/index/company-name-here-23`

the link will be converted

```
http://www.mydomain.com/display/company-name-here-23
```

Comment: 23 is actually an id number. and there might be thousands of company names in the database. I want this to be done dynamically from the db, not update my routes.php file manually.

Comment: I just update my question, obviosly i didn't clarify that 23 is an id, and i want to fetch the company name from my controller somehow, to avoid updating my routes.php manually. Sorry for that.

Comment: @user2417624, ok good, can you use company name instead on `id` in anchor link

Comment: can we go on chat? do you have 10 min of free time?

Comment: how to send invitation for chat here? looking for a link but i can't found it

Comment: @user2417624 comment will be automatic changed in chat, you just start what you want to konw

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49951/discussion-between-girish-and-user2417624)